# jQuery Blog Plugin

Tags: jquery, blogs, blogger

Has anyone encountered a jQuery plugin that allows you to display blog posts on your website (like the twitter plugin for jQuery). It can be for any blog, but ideally blogger.

Cheers.

Comment: Really? That's not a question about programming.

Comment: Its for a programming project...

Comment: @Soner Gönül - From my perspective it is about programming. He is just trying to save some time.

Comment: Cheers, I wasn't being lazy I really could only find the 3 twitter plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of the fact Blogger makes posts available via RSS. You can parse this using the jQuery rss plugin ([see here](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/rss)). You will need to do some coding yourself, but this fits nicely since it is a programming project.